# altering Windows environment variables permanently: how to "flush" for immediate effect?

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, registry, environment-variables

In a Windows `.bat` file, I'm trying to extend the system path permanently, and am following the instructions found in many places (for example, https://superuser.com/questions/390701 )

However, I'm not seeing the system path get updated in practice - at least, not immediately.  Something seems to need to be flushed first, and I'm not sure what.

I'm doing:

```
@SET "MyDirectory=C:\My\Fantastic\Application\bin"

@SET "EnvKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
@FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%a IN (`REG QUERY "%EnvKey%" /v Path`) do @set "OldPath=%%~b"
@REG ADD "%EnvKey" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%OldPath%;%MyDirectory%
```

This "works" in that the registry key in question subsequently looks correct when I refresh my `regedit` window. It also "works" in the sense that going to Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables->Path->Edit shows me the correct new value.

However, **here's the problem**: if I execute the above, then go Run->cmd to open a new command window, and type `echo %Path%`, I still see the *old* value, not the new (and of course, if I try to run my fantastic application, it is not found).  If I open the environment variables control-panel again and press "OK" *before* doing "Run->cmd", then something somewhere seems to get updated and the new Path will be valid, but I don't want my users to have to do anything like this by hand.

What am I missing?

Footnotes:  The above failure was observed in WinXP SP3.  I'm using `REG ADD` rather than `SETX` because I want this to work on old WinXP systems that don't seem to have `SETX`.   The trailing quote is missing deliberately from the `REG ADD` line as recommended in the answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/501528 . The incredibly nasty voodoo `FOR /F` line is necessary to prevent expansion of any variable names that might be *inside* the Path variable value, as would happen if you just did `@SET "OldPath=%Path%"`

Comment: That's as-expected.  You need to broadcast a window message (which SETX does, as does PATHMAN) to inform applications of the change.  You can't do this from a batch file, you have to have an external application to do it for you (or reboot the machine).

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20656609/2861476) could help you.