# Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the same command prompt in Windows?

Tags: batch-file

I need to update the value of val2 in the same command prompt. Val2 is an environment variable, which I am using from vcxproj file. val2 will contain different value depend on different target. How can I refresh/update the value of val2 in same command prompt?

```
@echo OFF


cd 8909

echo start the script 

readelf qcdsp28909.mbn -l | awk '{if (match($6,/0x/)){if ($1 == "LOAD" ) print strtonum($6)}}'|  awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024/1024}' > value.txt 2>&1

set /p size=<value.txt

echo %size%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a  in ("%size%") do (
  set first_part=%%a
  set second_part=%%b
)

set second_part=%second_part:~0,1%
echo %second_part%
if defined second_part if %second_part% GEQ 5 ( 

    set /a rounded=%first_part%+1
) else ( 
    set /a rounded=%first_part%
)

echo %rounded%

set /a rounded= "%rounded% * 1024 * 1024"

echo %rounded%

call cmd /c exit /b %rounded%
set hex=%=exitcode%

echo %hex%

SetX -m val2 "%hex%"

echo %val2%

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable is needed in the same command prompt window, then just set the variable

```
set "val2=%hex%"
```

But if what you need is to refresh the variable in the current user session, then better read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20656609/2861476)

Comment: Thanks for the command. But above command set the value in current window, but not setting it to ENV variable. Is their any command which can set the value for current and Env variable both. So, that If I open new cmd prompt my new value should reflect?

Comment: @PriyankKumarDalal, your options are: restart the session, kill every explorer instance or use the code (or similar) in the linked answer.

Comment: If my cmd prompt is opened fresh, at that time setx is not setting the env variable which is currently in used. It is setting to new cmd prompt. I am looking out for command which can update the existing cmd prompt

Comment: @PriyankKumarDalal, you can't. The code in the linked answer is able to notify the top processes in the system that the environment has changed so they update their environment variables and new opened consoles or programs will see the variable as the environments are a copy of the environment in the parent process. But this will not affect existing console windows. You can change the current console window by just using `set var=value`, and any console started from here will get the variable. But you can not change the environment of another already opened console.